# questions and tags options are missing?

Tags: discussion, support

I am using android smartphone and opera mini browser (because it uses less data) but when I visit beta sites I find that questions and tags options are missing (but actually it is hidden in the search bar above)

I thinks its not an bug (the problem might be with my browser)

I am just sharing this ...

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need - Opera Mini is not supported.